# Cannot debug Ruby on M1 mac (RubyMine)

Tags: ruby, rubygems

```
/bin/zsh -c "bash -c '/Users/darshan.shah/.rvm/bin/rvm ruby-2.7.5 do /Users/darshan.shah/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/bin/ruby -x /Users/darshan.shah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/bin/bundle exec /Users/darshan.shah/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/bin/ruby /Users/darshan.shah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/ruby-debug-ide-2.3.7/bin/rdebug-ide --key-value --step-over-in-blocks --disable-int-handler --evaluation-timeout 10 --evaluation-control --time-limit 100 --memory-limit 0 --rubymine-protocol-extensions --port 65292 --host 0.0.0.0 --dispatcher-port 65293 -- /Users/darshan.shah/workspace/{Workspace}/{rubyFileToRun}.rb chorus_editor.local77'"
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, /Users/darshan.shah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/bin is not at first place.
         Usually this is caused by shell initialization files. Search for PATH=... entries.
         You can also re-add RVM to your profile by running: rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles
         To fix it temporarily in this shell session run: rvm use ruby-2.7.5
         To ignore this error add rvm_silence_path_mismatch_check_flag=1 to your ~/.rvmrc file.


Traceback (most recent call last):
    5: from /Users/darshan.shah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/ruby-debug-ide-2.3.7/bin/rdebug-ide:5:in `<main>'
    4: from /Users/darshan.shah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/ruby-debug-ide-2.3.7/bin/rdebug-ide:5:in `require'
    3: from /Users/darshan.shah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/ruby-debug-ide-2.3.7/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    2: from /Users/darshan.shah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/ruby-debug-ide-2.3.7/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:5:in `require'
    1: from /Users/darshan.shah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/debase-2.3.7/lib/debase.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'

/Users/darshan.shah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/debase-2.3.7/lib/debase.rb:7:in `require': dlopen(/Users/darshan.shah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/debase-2.3.7/lib/debase_internals.bundle, 0x0009): tried: '/Users/darshan.shah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/debase-2.3.7/lib/debase_internals.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')) - /Users/darshan.shah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/debase-2.3.7/lib/debase_internals.bundle (LoadError)
```